# Cant access into ubuntu server using putty in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, virtualbox, putty

I have ubuntu server installed in virtualbox and the host os is windows 7.
I need to access into that ubuntu server using putty.
Now the way to access via putty is to, have two adapter in virtual box one should be **NAT** and another one should be **Bridged Adapter** everything is fine and in my virtual server there is internet connection as well, to check the internet i use this in my ubuntu server:

```
wget http://www.google.com
```

And it successfully downloads a `index.html` page on the directory.
But once i write in ubuntu terminal

```
ifconfig
```

then it dosen't show a working IP address that i can access via putty.
[image]
And when i try with that ip via putty it shows error :/
[image]
[image]
What's wrong with this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `eth0` interface is the NAT one. It only allows outgoing traffic by default.

In order to access the VM through a bridged interface, there should be an `eth1` entry in your ifconfig output. Double check you properly enabled and configured the second NIC in VirtualBox.

Alternatively, you can also stay with NAT only and configure port forwarding: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Ubuntu Server you need to manually create network interface to get eth1. To do so follow these steps below,

- Go to:
  sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
- Add the eth1 to the file you opened in above step:

  auto eth1

  iface eth1 inet dhcp
- close the file by pressing ctrl + X and save it by pressing y while closing( Or you can use your own editor which you like, I used nano editor)
- Reboot your system and your new eth1 will be available now.
- Now from your vm use ifconfig and now your eth1 address
- go to putty and and use eth1 address and login
- Note if still not works try to install ssh server in your VM and try again. Command is given below:

sudo apt-get install openssh-server